# Is it possible to create indexes for a string/uuid-based primary key to be able to fast search by similarity (e.g. noisy uuids)?

Tags: sql, indexing, ocr, similarity

I will give the concrete case for better comprehension.
I have some codes that I will call here UUID coming from OCR.

From the, say, 25 characters, a few are misrecognized.
Is it possible to "index by similarity" the UUID column in a SQL database?

Will a SELECT ... LIKE statement already have a good behavior, supposing only one character is wrong per UUID and I perform 25 queries?

[The noisy uuid is not going to be inserted, just SELECTed.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, i don't know if there is a built in funtion to do so but what you are trying to do is an algorithm called Levenshtein distance. Have a look at that :

Definition :
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:~:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965).

Using SQL :
[https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/#:~:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,not%20match%20exactly%20the%20fields](https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,not%20match%20exactly%20the%20fields).

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data that goes into the database -- or at least have the original code and an imputed code.

If you need to keep the original code, then my suggestion would be a look-up table with the original code and imputed code.  This table would be used for queries that want to filter by the actual code.

To give a concrete example, if I have a column with US state abbreviations and one of the codes was RA, I would not want to "automatically" figure out if this is :

- AR backwards (Arkansas)
- RI (Rhode Island)
- CA (California)
- MA (Massachusetts)
- PA (Pennsylvania)
- VA (Virginia)
- WA (Washington)

It seems like a manual effort would be required.